# Angular how to display data from user which contain an array

Tags: angular

I'm working on RecipesApp (Asp.Net MVC + Angular as a View)

I have User which contain ICollection of Recipes

What i'm trying to do is:

Display all recipes from User.

Smth like that *ngFor let user of user.recipes

{{user.recipes}}

What i've already tried
My user class:

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    knownAs: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    created: Date;
    lastActive: Date;
    photoUrl: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    introduction?: string;
    userPhotos?: UserPhoto[];
    recipes?: Recipe[];
}
```

MyComponent

```
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  recipes: Recipe[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user.recipes = data.user;
    });
  }
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    {{user.username}}
    <br>
    <hr>
    <p class="text-center">User Recipes: </p>

    <!-- <div *ngFor="let user of user" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      </div> -->
    </div>
```

@EDIT

My resolver:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { Resolve, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';


@Injectable()
export class MemberDetailResolver implements Resolve<User> {

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private alertify: AlertifyService) {

    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User> {
        return this.userService.getUser(route.params.id).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving data');
                this.router.navigate(['/members']);
                return of(null);
            })
        );

    }
}
```

Recipe class

```
export interface Recipe {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    ingredients: string;
    preparationTime: number;
    dateAdded: Date;
    photoUrl: string;
    description?: string;
    recipePhotos?: RecipePhoto[];
}
```

Comment: `*ngFor="let recipe of user.recipes"`

Comment: In view i got "<div *ngFor="let user of user.Recipes class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">"

Comment: What is stored in data.user?

Comment: I edited post and included what is inside data.user

Comment: Console your user.data, and tell what's inside no need of resolver code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in you .html:

in your ts you need to do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user= data.user; //here change
    });
  }
```

and in your html (I suppose recipes class has a property name)

```
     <div  *ngFor="let recipe of user.recipes" >
      <p>{{recipe.name}}</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: I edit my answer. I display the username but you can change with {{ recipe.id}} to display id! is it work?

Comment: On console i got "Cannot read property 'recipes' of undefined"

Comment: you are changing your question! you are doing a little bit of confusion! you need to publish also recipe class because you use recipes but you puglish only user class and not recipes

Comment: sorry, i thought that's enough to solve my problem :/

Comment: @BartolV9 are you sure your solution is correct? for me it's not work